# How to display one image if printing, another if viewing in browser?

Tags: css, printing

The header of my web site is made up of two images (one floated left, the other right) inside of
a `#header` div.

It renders beautifully in all browsers, but when I try to print the page, the images show up but
the background color of the `#header` div does not.

How do I fix this?

Comment: your question title and description are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Cynthia, if you're going to do something like this, I'd say what would make the most sense would be to use the `print-header.gif` image as the source for both images.

This method is called a CSS **sprite**. You use CSS positioning to only show the parts of the image that you want in `.header-left` and `.header-right` for screen. For print, you can expand `.header-left` to show the entire image and hide header-right. It means you've one less `<img>` on the page and are cutting down on HTTP requests (one for the image vs three).

Normally, this method would only be used on background images (which brings you back to step 1!), but it can be used with foreground images using the `clip` property. You CSS would be along the lines of:

**screen.css:**

```
div#header {
    position: relative;
}

img.header-left {
    position: absolute;
    clip:rect(top, right, bottom, left);
}

img.header-right {
    position: absolute;
    clip:rect(top, right, bottom, left);
    top: offset;
    left: offset;
}
```

**print.css:**

```
img.header-left {
    position: static;
    clip: auto;
}

img.header-right {
    display: none;
}
```

Your HTML could then be

```
<div id="header">
   <img src="/images/print-header.gif" class="header-left" />
   <img src="/images/print-header.gif" class="header-right" />
</div>
```

Comment: I agree, that would work perfectly, if both parts of the header (from the browser side) were just images. In this case, the header-left image is just an image, whereas the header-right image is a background image for a header content block (a date picker). Since the date picker is not needed when printing, a single alternative header image fits the bill.

Comment: @Cynthia, I was just going by the HTML you've provided below, where both header items were images… If that's not the case, you really need to give more detail in your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `media-query` like that:

```
#header { width: 100%; height: 100px; }

@media screen
{ 
    #header > #left { background: url("display1.png"); }
    #header > #right { background: url("display2.png"); }
}

@media print
{ 
    #header > #left { background: url("print.png"); }
    #header > #right { display: none; }
}
```

And then insert in your HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Except that the header on the browser side *has* to be 2 separate images, not one. So assigning a background image to the div doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers now are economic, by default they are not printing any background-color anymore.

Some browsers like FireFox let you manage that, but thats a per user setting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `media="print"`:

```
<style type="text/css">
#img{background-image:url('img1.jpg');}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
#img{background-image:url('img2.jpg');}
</style>
```

But if the problem is that the browser doesn't print background colors and you use Firefox, you can do:

File > Page Setup... > Format & Options > Options > Print Background (colors & images)

or

Firefox Button > Print... > Page Setup... > Format & Options > Options > Print Background (colors & images)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

I created a second header image that combined the two original images (plus a little padding to
make it look nice) to use ONLY for printing.

Here is how I got the image to show up for printing but not be visible at any other time:

I created a class called `.print-header` and in my main style.css I set it up like so:

```
.print-header { display:none }
```

In my print.css I set it up like so:

```
.print-header { display:block !important }
.header-left { display:none } /* this hides the original left header image when printing */
.header-right { display:none } /* this hides the original right header image when printing */
```

And then changed my HTML to:

```
<div id="header">
   <img src="/images/logo.gif" class="header-left" />
   <img src="/images/cta.gif" class="header-right" />
   <img src="/images/print-header.gif" class="print-header" />
</div>
```

and voila! In the browser, the original 2-image header displays and when printing, the single 
image header displays.

Comment: It may not be pretty, but it is valid markup and it works across the board. The header on the browser side has to be two separate sections (header-left and header-right) for content reasons. It doesn't need to be for the print view. So an alternate print-only header made the most sense.